# C# Json.NET convert string to JSON key

Tags: c#, json, linq, json.net

My app is accepting user input as json key, how can I convert string `a[0].b` to json key?

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

string keys = "a[0].b";
dynamic js = dynamic js = JObject.Parse("{'a': [{'b' : 'hello'}, {'b': 'world'}]}");

//Console.WriteLine(js.a[0].b); // world

Console.WriteLine(js["a[0].b"]); // error
Console.WriteLine(js[keys]); // error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will find it challenging to find anything a user might input, but assuming you want "hello" from your example then you should parse to `JObject` instead of dynamic so that you can use `SelectToken` or `SelectTokens` with a string path:

```
string keys = "a[0].b";
JObject js = JObject.Parse("{'a': [{'b' : 'hello'}, {'b': 'world'}]}");
string hello = js.SelectToken(keys).ToString();
```